tsDyn library doesn't load in R Studion
I can't get the tsDyn Library to load.  I have tried to uninstall and install the package multiple times and have gotten different error messages, all of which I have attempted to address.
The latest version of error message is as follows:
Show in New Window
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tsDyn’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘fracdiff’
I had previously installed the fracdiff package but it kept freezing the R Studio whenever I tried some of its functions. I currently don't have the 'fracdiff' installed.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

So the problem is you can't do it without fracdiff ... so your question is really how do I get fracdiff to install?  Can you try that and add the error messages or else close this and open a new question about fracdiff.
